# Refreshing access token when REST API returns 401 in Retrofit2 RxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have the following endpoints in REST API:

```java
public interface AutomoticzAPI {

    @POST("/api/beacon_auth/login")
    Single<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest request);

    @GET("/api/system/ws_devices")
    Single<WSDevicesResponse> wsDeviceList(@Header("Authorization") String tokenHeader);

}
```

When I call `login` endpoint, in response I recieve access token that I save into `ClientSession` holder object. Later I can retrieve token from `ClientSession` use to call server's protected resources:

```java
        api.login(ClientSession.getInstance().getLoginRequest(login, password))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(loginResponse -> {
                    String accessToken = loginResponse.getAccessToken();
                    ClientSession.getInstance().setAccessToken(accessToken);
                    view.onLoginSuccess();
                }, throwable -> {
                    RetrofitException exception = (RetrofitException) throwable;
                    if (exception.getKind().equals(RetrofitException.Kind.HTTP)){
                        view.onLoginFailed(exception.getMessage());
                    } else if(exception.getKind().equals(RetrofitException.Kind.NETWORK))
                    {
                        view.onLoginFailed("Network error...");
                    } else {
                        view.onLoginFailed("Unknown error occurred...");
                    }
                });
```

When I'm calling `wsDeviceList` endpoint, server could return 401 HTTP response code and json body with error code and message:

```
{
    "code": "EXPIRED-TOKEN",
    "message": "Token expired"
}
```

If that happens I want to call login endpoint once again to get new access token. Here is my code so far:

```java
    ClientSession clientSession = ClientSession.getInstance();
    String token = "Bearer "+clientSession.getAccessToken();
    String url = ClientSession.getInstance().getUrl();
    AutomoticzAPI api = NetworkManager.getApiClient(url);
    api.wsDeviceList(token)
            .retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> throwableFlowable.flatMap(
                    new Function<Throwable, Publisher<?>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Publisher<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            RetrofitException exception = (RetrofitException) throwable;
                            if (exception.isUnauthorizedError()){
                                return relogin(api, clientSession.getLoginRequest());
                            }
                            return (Publisher<?>) throwable;
                        }
                    }
            ))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(wsDevicesResponse -> {
                view.onDeviceListLoaded(wsDevicesResponse.getWsdevices());
            }, throwable -> {
                RetrofitException exception = (RetrofitException) throwable;
                view.onError(exception);
            });
}

public Publisher<?> relogin(AutomoticzAPI api, LoginRequest loginRequest){
    return (Publisher<?>) api.login(loginRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(loginResponse -> {
                String accessToken = loginResponse.getAccessToken();
                ClientSession.getInstance().setAccessToken(accessToken);
            }, throwable -> {
                RetrofitException exception = (RetrofitException) throwable;
                view.onError(exception);
            });
}
```

But when `relogin` method gets executed my program crashes. 
I'm not proficient in RxJava and probably doing this wrong. How I can make recall `login` to refresh access token and then call `wsDeviceList` once again?

Comment: Use Okhttps' Authenticator which provides a mechanism for handling just this case. https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#handling-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Authenticator API of retrofit and inside this call access token api to get access token and re try the fail API call using this access token.